# HTML/CSS text flows downwards after shrinking and container wont shrink and it takes too much of page

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with my text, I have this problem when I shrink the page my text instead of flowing to the right it shrinks down and becomes too large as you see in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOE9X.jpg) and the other text wont fit the image size. I need help.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a base font size for the entire document */
}



body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Cursive, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(46, 102, 46, 60%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.25rem 6.25rem; /* Use rem for padding */
    background: seagreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 105;
}

nav {
    z-index: 1;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav a {
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for margin */
}

h1 {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.explore {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

h1, .explore {
    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.explore {
    font-size: 1.25rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 50%;
    top: 110%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.aboutDC {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 50%;
    top: 130%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

/* Capitol building picture and text */

.capitolp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 236%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    margin-right: 37.5rem; /* Use rem for margin */
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.bull {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 197%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 170%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

/* Washington monument picture and text */
.monumentImg {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 74%;
    top: 197%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: right;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.monumentP {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 79%;
    top: 235%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    margin-left: -6rem;
    min-width: 50rem; /* Use rem for min-width */
    border: 3px solid red;
}

h5 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 74%;
    top: 170%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Reset styles for smaller screens to match larger screens */
    
    body {
        font-size: 0.8rem; /* Reset font size to the default value */
    }

    .capitolp{
        max-height: 4rem;
        width: min-content;
    }
    h4{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    h5{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    .monumentImg{
        min-width: 50%;
       height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .bull{
        min-width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
} 

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .monumentImg{
        min-width: 50%;
        width: 640px;
        height: 427px;
    }

}
@media(max-width: 1640px ) {
    .capitolp, .monumentP{
        font-size: 1rem;

    }
    
}* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a base font size for the entire document */
}



body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Cursive, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(46, 102, 46, 60%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.25rem 6.25rem; /* Use rem for padding */
    background: seagreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 105;
}

nav {
    z-index: 1;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav a {
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for margin */
}

h1 {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.explore {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

h1, .explore {
    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.explore {
    font-size: 1.25rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 50%;
    top: 110%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.aboutDC {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 50%;
    top: 130%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

/* Capitol building picture and text */

.capitolp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 236%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    margin-right: 37.5rem; /* Use rem for margin */
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.bull {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 197%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 28%;
    top: 170%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

/* Washington monument picture and text */
.monumentImg {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 74%;
    top: 197%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: right;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.monumentP {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 79%;
    top: 235%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    margin-left: -6rem;
    min-width: 50rem; /* Use rem for min-width */
    border: 3px solid red;
}

h5 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 74%;
    top: 170%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Reset styles for smaller screens to match larger screens */
    
    body {
        font-size: 0.8rem; /* Reset font size to the default value */
    }

    .capitolp{
        max-height: 4rem;
        width: min-content;
    }
    h4{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    h5{
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
    .monumentImg{
        min-width: 50%;
       height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .bull{
        min-width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
} 

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .monumentImg{
        min-width: 50%;
        width: 640px;
        height: 427px;
    }

}
@media(max-width: 1640px ) {
    .capitolp, .monumentP{
        font-size: 1rem;

    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rs">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Projetak</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <h3>LOGO</h3>
     
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#welcome-section">Explore Washington DC</a>
                    <a href="#aboutDC">About</a>
                      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          
               </nav>
            </header>
       <main>
         <img class="background" src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/gl4X9QFZaajTUmYXLgcaJTV0S3msMB3j5WPX-f8-YZk/rs:fit:860:0:0/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly93YWxs/cGFwZXJiYXQuY29t/L2ltZy8zMjQ3NjQt/d2FzaGluZ3Rvbi1k/Yy13YWxscGFwZXIt/d29ybGQtd2FsbHBh/cGVyLWRlc2t0b3At/YmFja2dyb3VuZC5q/cGc" alt="background">
               <section id="welcome-section">
                <div>
                    <h1>Washington DC</h1>
                    <p class="explore">Explore the beauty of Washington DC</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            </main>

               <section id="projects">
                <div class="about">
                    <h2>About Washington DC</h2>  
                </div>
                <div>
                   <p class="aboutDC" id="aboutDC">
                    Washington, D.C., the capital of the United States, is a vibrant city rich in history and culture. Known for its iconic landmarks such as the White House, the Capitol Building, and the Washington Monument, the city offers a blend of political significance and captivating attractions. Explore the museums of the Smithsonian Institution, stroll through the National Mall, or immerse yourself in the city's diverse culinary scene. Washington, D.C. is a place where history comes alive, and modernity thrives,
                     making it a must-visit destination for travelers from around the world.
                   </p>
                </div>  
               </section>
            <section id="CapitolBuilding">
                <div class="Building">
                    <div>
                    <h4>The United States Capitol</h4>
                </div>
                   
                    <img class="bull" src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/csL7mQCRlpzZcXTPqrlHZrL8Xiq0B4OsLSWhalKX9Rc/rs:fit:860:0:0/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4u/cGl4YWJheS5jb20v/cGhvdG8vMjAxMy8w/My8yNi8wMC8zMS9j/YXBpdG9sLTk2ODI3/XzY0MC5qcGc" alt="U.S. Capitol">
                </div>
                    <div>

                    <p class="capitolp">
               The United States Capitol, often referred to simply as the Capitol, is an architectural masterpiece located
                in the heart of Washington, D.C. It houses the two chambers of the United States Congress, the Senate,
                and the House of Representatives. The neoclassical design of the Capitol, with its iconic white dome and impressive columns,
                is not only a symbol of American governance but also a testament to the nation's enduring commitment to democracy. Visitors
                   to the Capitol can explore its historic chambers, marvel at the stunning artwork and statues that adorn its halls, and learn
                   about the rich history and legislative process that have shaped the United States. The U.S. Capitol stands as a beacon of
                     freedom and a cornerstone of American politics and history.
                    </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="WashingtonMonument">
                    <div>
                    <h5>The Washington Monument</h5>
                    </div>
                <img class="monumentImg" src="https://assets.editorial.aetnd.com/uploads/2013/10/gettyimages-1133774747.jpg" alt="Washington Monument Building">
            </div>
               <div>
                <p class="monumentP">
                    The Washington Monument, an iconic obelisk, stands proudly in the heart of the National Mall in Washington, D.C. This majestic monument was built to honor George
                     Washington, the first President of the United States and a founding father. It is a symbol of the nation's respect and admiration for his leadership and
                      contributions to American history. Rising to a height of 555 feet, it offers breathtaking panoramic views of the city and its many landmarks. Visitors can learn
                       about the monument's construction and its historical significance while taking in the beauty of its marble exterior. The Washington Monument is not only a
                        towering structure but also a testament to the enduring legacy of one of America's greatest leaders.
                </p>
            </div>
                
            </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried the  `@media` and `position` `display` and nothing seems to work so i need help
EDIT: also tried to make the font smaller but it doesen't work

Comment: Please clarify how you wish this to flow.  Text below. text scroll, image then text then next image, etc. as the view window narrows

Comment: i want it image then text and the text to be the size of the image

Comment: As I said on your last post about this, you must use flexbox or grid to add responsiveness to your site https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp / https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: i read that thing, tried flex-wrap and flex-direction and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the code and revised a bit. It works as intended. But I can't explain line by line. Because, I had to chance a lot of things. The problem is that some fundamentals are missing:

1. Understanding CSS Positioning: There was a lot unnecessary "position: absolute;" css property. It is useful to check how positioning works, but when you know flexbox or grid you mostly don't need to deal with positioning unless you want to achieve some overlapping on elements, like you did with background image.[MDN Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
2. Modern CSS layout methods. Understanding this, solves 90% of your problems. No exaggeration!: [MDN Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout) (I advise to check for flexbox first. Grid can be overwhelming at the beginning.) (Also there is a fun game called [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)
3. Semantic HTML: There was a couple unnecessary wrapper div Mostly try to use semantic because of Search Engine Optimization (SEO) And also since its semantic it's easy to abstract the page layout. [Semantics in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html)
4. CSS Selectors: class names should be reusable and start with lowercase. ids are unique and mostly for JS or specific css rules to apply. [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)

I advise to check this:
[web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px; /* Set a base font size for the entire document */
}

body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  font-family: Cursive, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(46, 102, 46, 60%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 4rem 0 0 0;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

article {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  padding-block: 1rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.25rem 6.25rem; /* Use rem for padding */
  background: seagreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 105;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2rem; /* Use rem for font size */
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 1.125rem; /* Use rem for font size */
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for margin */
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100dvh;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem; /* Use rem for font size */
}

.img__article {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.article__title {
  text-align: center;
}

.articles__wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.article__paragraph {
    min-height: 10em;
    height: min-content;
}

.padding__top__bottom {
    padding-block: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rs">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Projetak</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <span>LOGO</span>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#welcome-section">Explore Washington DC</a>
                    <a href="#aboutDC">About</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>
    <main id="welcome-section">
        <img class="background"
            src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/gl4X9QFZaajTUmYXLgcaJTV0S3msMB3j5WPX-f8-YZk/rs:fit:860:0:0/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly93YWxs/cGFwZXJiYXQuY29t/L2ltZy8zMjQ3NjQt/d2FzaGluZ3Rvbi1k/Yy13YWxscGFwZXIt/d29ybGQtd2FsbHBh/cGVyLWRlc2t0b3At/YmFja2dyb3VuZC5q/cGc"
            alt="background" loading="lazy">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Washington DC</h1>
            <h2 class="explore">Explore the beauty of Washington DC</h2>
        </div>
    </main>
    <main id="aboutDC" class="padding__top__bottom">
        <section>
            <h2>About Washington DC</h2>
            <!-- <p class="aboutDC" id="aboutDC"> -->
            <!-- mostly use id to call element for some interactivity with javascript if you have a reason. -->
            <!-- <p class="aboutDC"> -->
            <!-- You might want to give a generic name since you possibly use it in another place. -->
            <p class="">
                Washington, D.C., the capital of the United States, is a vibrant city rich in history and culture. Known
                for its iconic landmarks such as the White House, the Capitol Building, and the Washington Monument, the
                city offers a blend of political significance and captivating attractions. Explore the museums of the
                Smithsonian Institution, stroll through the National Mall, or immerse yourself in the city's diverse
                culinary scene. Washington, D.C. is a place where history comes alive, and modernity thrives,
                making it a must-visit destination for travelers from around the world.
            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="articles__wrapper">
            <article>
                <!-- <div class="Building"> -->
                <!-- it is good to have class name starts with lowercase.  -->
                <!-- when you are selecting an html tag to style, it will apply all others so you might want to consider give a class name. -->
                <h4 class="article__title">The United States Capitol</h4>
                <img class="img__article"
                    src="https://imgs.search.brave.com/csL7mQCRlpzZcXTPqrlHZrL8Xiq0B4OsLSWhalKX9Rc/rs:fit:860:0:0/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4u/cGl4YWJheS5jb20v/cGhvdG8vMjAxMy8w/My8yNi8wMC8zMS9j/YXBpdG9sLTk2ODI3/XzY0MC5qcGc"
                    alt="U.S. Capitol">
                <!-- you might want to check what is lazy loading -->
                <p class="article__paragraph">
                    The United States Capitol, often referred to simply as the Capitol, is an architectural
                    masterpiece
                    located
                    in the heart of Washington, D.C. It houses the two chambers of the United States Congress, the
                    Senate,
                    and the House of Representatives. The neoclassical design of the Capitol, with its iconic white
                    dome
                    and
                    impressive columns,
                    is not only a symbol of American governance but also a testament to the nation's enduring
                    commitment
                    to
                    democracy. Visitors
                    to the Capitol can explore its historic chambers, marvel at the stunning artwork and statues
                    that
                    adorn
                    its halls, and learn
                    about the rich history and legislative process that have shaped the United States. The U.S.
                    Capitol
                    stands as a beacon of
                    freedom and a cornerstone of American politics and history.
                </p>
            </article>

            <!-- you might want to check "Semantic HTML". -->
            <article>
                <h4 class="article__title">The Washington Monument</h4>
                <img class="img__article"
                    src="https://assets.editorial.aetnd.com/uploads/2013/10/gettyimages-1133774747.jpg"
                    alt="Washington Monument Building">
                <p class="article__paragraph">
                    The Washington Monument, an iconic obelisk, stands proudly in the heart of the National Mall in
                    Washington, D.C. This majestic monument was built to honor George
                    Washington, the first President of the United States and a founding father. It is a symbol of
                    the
                    nation's respect and admiration for his leadership and
                    contributions to American history. Rising to a height of 555 feet, it offers breathtaking
                    panoramic
                    views of the city and its many landmarks. Visitors can learn
                    about the monument's construction and its historical significance while taking in the beauty of
                    its
                    marble exterior. The Washington Monument is not only a
                    towering structure but also a testament to the enduring legacy of one of America's greatest
                    leaders.
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>

    </main>

</body>

</html>
```